# How do I change the title of an HTML page generated by Docco?

Tags: javascript, documentation, docco

Currently the title of any HTML page generated by Docco will be the name of the source code file. How do I change that? I would like to set a custom title for my generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that the first line in your source file has a header section in it, for example:

```
//  # My Custom Title
var code = require('somelib');
```

The above code, when given as an input to docco, will result in an HTML page with title "My Custom Title".